# Android WebService Com erro ao usar Android 4.2

Tags: java, android

Olá ,estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que preciso pegar e enviar valores pra um servidor.
Fiz tudo e funcionou perfeitamente na versão 7.0 do android,porém ao ir para 4.2,começa a dar erro.

Estou usando um Asynctask para fazer o request,enviando e recebendo resposta do servidor.

```
  public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromURL(String urlString) throws IOException, JSONException, MalformedURLException, ProtocolException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("CODIGOOOOOOOO:"+statusCode);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();

    String jsonString = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

    return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.12/projeto/Cadastrarformularios.php?json=[{"Modalidade":"Presencial","Unidade":"belem","Email":"1@d.com","CPF":"1","Sobrenome":"sobrenome","Fone":"1","Cod_Consultor":"1001","Data_Cadastro":"2017-11-18 22:49:40","Curso":"autonomia","Nome":"1","Celular":"1"}]
```

Pelo o que percebi,está retornando o erro 400,porem não sei por que não funciona pelo android,copiando o link o servidor reconhece normalmente,e funciona normalmente no android 7.0

@edit
Na versão 6.0 também não pega,só na 7.0

OBS: Por algum motivo,ao usuário fazer o login,ele consegue logar normalmente e o código para a autenticação é a mesma postada.
Agradeço desde já pela ajuda !

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.
Troquei o método GET pelo Método POST

```
 public JSONObject  performPostCall(String requestURL,String parametro) throws JSONException {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write("json="+parametro);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new JSONObject(response);
}
```

Se alguém poder me explicar o por que do GET não funcionar eu ficaria agradecido,eu estou achando que é por causa dos caracteres [{... na URL